# How can i run java command as a service Centos 5?

Tags: centos

i want to execute  `java -cp server.jar:mysql.jar server.NithServer` this command as linux service how can i do that. & not working. centos 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's about using [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)?
It provides cross platform way of running java applications as services and also have a community version that should be enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

A seriously written service must have the bash script that accepts start, stop and restart parameters. Such script can be copied or better linked (original at /etc/init.d) to /etc/rc3.d or /etc/rc5.d and will be maintained by the system, executing shutdown and startup when required. [Here](http://www.doitscared.com/123/installing-tomcat-as-a-linux-service/) there is a tutorial how to wrap Apache Tomcat as a service.